# First time using scrapy, trying to crawl a set of tables

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I am very new to Python (and new to stackoverflow) and have just started with Scrapy. I am looking to grab some hobby product information from different websites. I have read through the tutorial and am feeling pretty lsot. What I want are the attributes of watches that are listed in tables but they all have the same class ("productTitle") in the second table.

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="productTitle creditCardPrice" valign="top">
        <strong>Regular Price:</strong>
      </td> 
      <td valign="top">$9,072</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="productTitle retailPrice" valign="top">
        <strong>Retail Price:</strong>
      </td> 
      <td valign="top">$12,350</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="productTitle itemNumber" valign="top">
        <strong>Item Number:</strong>
      </td> 
      <td valign="top">112555</td> 
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Second table:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 15px;">
      <td class="productTitle" style="height: 15px;" valign="top"> .     
        <strong>Manufacturer:</strong>
      </td> 
      <td style="height: 15px;" valign="top">Rolex</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 30px;">
      <td class="productTitle" style="height: 30px;" valign="top">
        <strong>Model Name/Number:</strong>
      </td> 
      <td style="height: 30px;" valign="top">Yacht-Master 116622</td> 
    </tr>
```

There are many more rows of data. You can see the example here: https://www.bobswatches.com/rolex-platinum-yacht-master-116622-pre-owned.html

My goal is to get all of this data into a .csv file with each column labeled with "Credit Card Price", "Manufacturer", "Model Name/Number" etc. and then crawl my favorite watches from the website and create an sheet with all these details for every watch. But, before I get to the part where the spider moves through different pages, I have to get it to crawl this one page correctly.

I do not see how to write this out using Scrapy. I am bouncing around to several other stackoverflow questions and playing with the tutorial still, but making very slow progress. This is clearly wrong, but where I am atm:

```
    def parse(self, response):
    for row in response.selector.xpath('//table'):
        yield {
            'text': row.xpath('./td[1]').extract_first(),
        }

    next_page_url = response.xpath('//li[@class="next"]/a/@href').extract_first()
    if next_page_url is not None:
        yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page_url))
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Scrapy+csv

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: @eLRuLL Added more to make that clear

Comment: I still don't understand. What do you mean with "*hobby product information from different websites*". If you can't format the table correctly, try creating a simpler example with similar structure. Also please specify which parts of the html you want to get.

Comment: More clarity added. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to extract structured data: row title and row data from that table?

You can achieve this by:

1. Extract all rows For each row
2. For each row extract a title and rows data

So it's just the matter of using right `xpath` selectors. For example something like this would do the trick:

```
# find all table rows
rows = response.xpath("//tr")
for row in rows:
    title = row.xpath(".//strong/text()").extract_first()
    text = ''.join(row.xpath(".//td/text()").extract()).strip('. \n')
    print(title)
    print(text)
    print('-'*80)
```

returns:

```
Regular Price:
$9,072
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Retail Price:
$12,350
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Item Number:
112555
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Regular Price:
$9,072
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Retail Price:
$12,350
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Item Number:
112555
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Manufacturer:
Rolex
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Model Name/Number:
Yacht-Master 116622
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```